# Showing a android screen only once on installation

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having an android layout having to input some of the basic details of the user.
This layout screen or activity has to come only once after installation, but it should not come up after successive opening of the application.
Could you let me know how can this be achieved in android.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can  put a flag in shared preferences that you showed once the screen and it's no need to show it again. But when the user clears data, the flag will be deleted. As a hard way, you can save this flag on a server or cloud.

Answer (score 0):

I think having a flag set in shared preference is the best way to do that. And i think if the user clears his cache , then he deserves to see the screen which is shown only once on installation. Similar is the behaviour which happens everywhere. Many websites store the user information in their cache and don't show user unnecessary information but if you clear the cache then you will see that information back again